# Induction on a Recursive Sequence?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, recursion, proof-explanation

So I don't really know where to go from here, or how to "guess a formula for an"

a0, a1,a2... is a sequence that a0 = a1 = 1 and, for n >= 1, an + 1 = n (an +an-1)

So I started off by doing the base case which is 1, and getting:

a1 + 1 = 1(a1 + a1-1)
1 + 1 = 1(1+1)
2 = 1(2)
2 = 2 Which checks out fine.

Then I assumed true for k, which was:

ak+1 = k(ak + ak -1)

Then I tried to prove for k+1, and got:

a(k+1)+1 = k+1(ak+1 + ak+1 -1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to try to guess the formula, we *calculate*. We find that $a_2=2$, $a_3=6$, $a_4=24$, $a_5=120$, $a_6=720$.

This sequence looks familiar, up to $n=6$ we have $a_n=n!$.

Now prove by (strong) induction that $a_{n}=n!$ for all non-negative integers $n$.

Suppose that $a_{i}=i!$ for all $i\le k$. We show that $a_{k+1}=(k+1)!$.
We have 
$$a_{k+1}=k(k!+(k-1)!)=k(k-1)!(k+1)=(k+1)!.$$ This completes the induction step.